# In Jekyll, how can I generate year pages?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'd like to be able to automatically generate by-year archive pages for every year in my blog history. That is, if I have at least one post from 2014, I'd like to be able to generate `/archive/2014/index.html`, and if I have at least one post from 2013, I'd like it to generate the page `/archive/2013/index.html`. Is there a way to do that in Jekyll?

Answer (score 1):

Jekyll doesn't provide that feature by default. However, one of the most common plugins is [jekyll-archives](https://rubygems.org/gems/jekyll-archives) that is capable to generate post archives by dates, tags, and categories.

However, just keep in mind that this plugin is not supported if you are using GitHub pages [as explained here](https://github.com/github/pages-gem/pull/106). Actually, in the post itself you can see it is really hard that GitHub will ever support year or categories archives in general.

Answer (score 1):

In case you can't use plugins *(for example if you need your site to work on GitHub Pages)*, you can create **one** page that contains all years.

This is possible without plugins, for an example see [Jekyll/Liquid Templating: How to group blog posts by year?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20777475/6884).

---

If you absolutely **must** have a separate page for each year and still can't use plugins, there's another way if you're okay with generating a page with two lines of YAML front-matter for each year.
[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28157853/6884) where I'm showing how to create tag/category pages *(separate page per tag)* without using plugins.
It's not that difficult to create something similar for the years of post dates.