# Posts by month in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, archive

I am trying to create an archive page of posts from my website. What I would like is to be able to have a pages for each list of posts by month in this format:

www.mywebsite.com/2016/11 would display all posts for November 2016.

Can I have a page for each month I have posted that is dynamically created each time I post in a new month? I don't want to have to manually create a new page for each month.

I already can group posts by year like so:

```
<ul>
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% assign currentdate = post.date | date: "%Y" %}
  {% if currentdate != date %}
    <li id="y{{currentdate}}">{{ currentdate }}</li>
    {% assign date = currentdate %} 
  {% endif %}
    <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify your `date` filter to integrate the month, e.g. `date: "%B %Y"`. That's what I used in a layout, with a separate `<ul>` for each month.

From [documentation](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/additional-filters#date), month-only values for the `date` filter are:

- `%b`: abbreviated month name.
- `%B`: full month name.
- `%m`: month of the year (01 - 12).

Complete loop:

```
<ul>
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% assign currentdate = post.date | date: "%B %Y" %}
  {% if currentdate != date %}
    <li id="y{{currentdate}}">{{ currentdate }}</li>
    {% assign date = currentdate %} 
  {% endif %}
    <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

About generating the pages, AFAIK this can only be done through a plugin. If you can't use plugins, e.g. if you're hosting your pages on GitHub, the best you can do is to reduce your pages to a short YAML frontmatter relying on a layout, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142299/jekyll-blog-show-posts-under-a-category/28157853#28157853).

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. I am hosting on GitHub, so I won't be using any plugins for this (and to be honest I want to keep the site as lightweight as possible, so I don't want any dependencies on external plugins).